# Image With Borders in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I want to apply different borders to image in my iphone application. I am capturing image from camera. and now i have some differnt borders, and i want to apply that border to image. How do i do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source
{
  CGSize size = [source size];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
  [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0); 
  CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
  UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return testImg;
}
```